# jquery validate: how to place error div

Tags: html, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validate to validate my form. It's a form with text and radio types and also with a selector.

The validation is working great, but when validating radio buttons the error div shows in between the buttons and not at the end of the row of them.

How can I place this div in a different position without moving it for the rest of the form's fields?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use the code from this exemple: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Gender</legend>
<label for="gender_male">
<input type="radio" id="gender_male" value="m" name="gender" validate="required:true" />
Male
</label>
<label for="gender_female">
<input type="radio" id="gender_female" value="f" name="gender"/>
Female
</label>
<label for="gender" class="error">Please select your gender</label>
</fieldset>
```

and change the 
`<label for="gender" class="error">`position